# Is it correct to say to a child "hold the chocolate by its cover/packet, not by the chocolate itself so you won't spread germs on it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]
You bought your child a chocolate bar and you ripped its cover/packet open but still left some packet/cover on the chocolate.

You wanted your child to hold the chocolate by holding the cover/packet part, not the chocolate itself part because germs from his/her fingers may be in contact with the chocolate.

Is it correct to say to a child "**hold the chocolate by its cover/packet, not by the chocolate itself so you won't spread germs on it**"?

Comment: The "cover" of a candy bar is usually called a [wrapper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrapper).

Comment: You may try *Lay hold of the chocolate wrapper* .

Comment: "Germs from your fingers?" Really? I was always taught to wash my hands before using them to eat.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, you can't wash your hands several times a day, which is not good as you may develop arthritis.

Comment: Hand washing is difficult or painful for people with arthritis, but the condition is not caused by the action of washing the hands. My wife works in a hospital pharmacy, and, like her whole team, washes her hands at least 20 times a day, as do doctors, nurses and all hospital staff.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, if i wash my hands more than 5 times, I feel burning in my knuckles